# How I make open menus and submenus when hover categories like udemy

Tags: css, menu, hover, submenu, bootstrapper

how i make  open menus and submenus when hover categories like udemy ( Categories )  If you are help me, I will enjoy

Comment: Could you show some code and your workout steps !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stack Overflow is not a tutorial provider. Askers are expected to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us the problems they are facing. Please review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic approach:

1. Make your dropdown item container's position `relative`,
2. Inside the dropdown item container, create nested submenu and position it `absolute`,
3. The nested menu ititially can be hidden (i.e: `display: none`, `visibility:hidden`)
4. On dropdown item container's hover, change the visibility.